# Проблема при использовании Sqlite в C#

Tags: c#, sqlite

Скачал с [официального сайта](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki) установщик и сами dll, распаковал, подключил         System.data.sqlite к проекту. При запуске программы выходит исключение:

```
Необработанное исключение типа "System.DllNotFoundException" в System.Data.SQLite.dll

Дополнительные сведения: Не удается загрузить DLL "SQLite.Interop.dll": Не найден        указанный модуль. (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

Код программы:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SQLite;
using System.IO;

namespace SqlCmd
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String path = @"database.db";
            File.Create(path).Close();  
            SQLiteConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(String.Format("DataSource={0}",path));
            cnn.Open();
            SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tab1(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, body TEXT);",cnn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cnn.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Не та разрядность библиотеки скорей всего. Устанавливайте данную либу при помощи NuGet и с этой проблемой не столкнетесь.

Comment: @maxus0706: Посмотрите внимательно в exception, там должен быть fusion log.

Comment: Устанавливай с помощью Nuget, ошибка потому что не хватает нативной библиотеки sqlitу, а то что ты подключил всего лишь .net обертка

Comment: Error 1 The type 'System.Data.Common.DbConnection' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. C:\Users\Роман\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\medprog\UnitTestMedprog\Core\Models\DAOTest.cs 17 13 UnitTestMedprog

установил так как вы сказали((( что делать?

Comment: В тексте ошибки написано же, как исправить.

Comment: Установил с помощью Nuget

Comment: You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data...'

Comment: скажите как - сделаю!

Comment: @5573352: Вы так говорите, как будто мы все заинтересованы, чтобы у вас получилось, а вы сидите в сторонке и отнекиваетесь.

Подключайте мозги, поищите, где в проекте "Add Reference". Воспользуйтесь гуглом, в конце-концов. Не ждите, пока вам разжуют и положат в рот.